# Azure Face group more than 1000 faces in call to Group API

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

The documentation for the Azure Face API says that the limit for faceIds in a call to Group is 1000. See: https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395238

Is there any way to raise this limit or another way to achive grouping of more than 1000 faces?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not, the limit of this api is still 1000 faces. You can vote up for this feature on the feedback [page](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/430315-face/suggestions/32866888-1000-face). The develop team may improve the limit in the future.